# Installing jnetpcap on a router

Tags: installation, router

Can jnetpcap be installed on a router? Someone said that it could. Their web page lists several OSes that it can be installed on, but I don't see anything about routers.

Comment: What kind of router do you have? All routers have OS's. Some are just crappy basement made firmwares, some are full blown unix or other os variants.

Comment: I have a linksys router with ddwrt installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out your `ddwrt` package list or search around. It doesn't look like it to me but there might be other libpcap based things that would do what you want.